# How to make window appear on top of all other windows?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am building a small application which performs updates on program files of another software and then launches this software. After starting the application, a splash window is shown in a second GUI thread, while on the main thread the main window of the second application is constructed and shown:

```
var shell = (Shell) Shell;
Application.Current.MainWindow = shell;
shell.Show();
```

After the shell of the second app is shown, the first window is closed. Everything is working fine, apart from that the shell of the second window is *popping under** other windows. I.e: I start the launcher app from the explorer, the launcher window shows on top of the explorer window. The launcher window closes and the main app window appears under the explorer window:

I've tried:

```
var shell = (Shell) Shell;
Application.Current.MainWindow = shell;
shell.Topmost = true;
shell.Show();
shell.InjectInitialViews();
```

which solves this problem, but then I am not able to show other windows above the shell, even if I click on another app in the task bar.

```
var shell = (Shell) Shell;
Application.Current.MainWindow = shell;
shell.Topmost = true;
shell.Show();
shell.InjectInitialViews();
shell.Topmost = false;
```

Doesn't do anything... Whats the proper way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the answers of Mike and Sheridan, I found the solution to be simply activating the window in the thread it is created in. So

```
var shell = (Shell) Shell;
Application.Current.MainWindow = shell;
shell.Topmost = true;
shell.Show();
shell.InjectInitialViews();
shell.Activate();
```

does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

There is no point in your second example, as the UI is *not* updated *during* program execution and therefore, your call to `shell.Topmost = true;` will be ignored. A better way to achieve what you want may be to handle the [`Window.Deactivated`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.deactivated%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and possibly [`Window.Activated`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.activated%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) events:

```
private void SecondWindow_Deactivated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MainWindow window = (MainWindow)sender;
    window.TopMost = true;
}
```

Comment: Hi SHeridan, thanks for your answer. A shell.Activate() is all that was missing, so you were pretty close with the events. I wasn't aware of the Activate() method, though it's really straight-forward. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, I solved this problem in a WPF Smart Client with an external launcher by doing the following:

1. After starting main application, the launcher calls `AllowSetForegroundWindow` via P/Invoke to allow the main application to set the foreground window (this is allowed if the launcher is active).
2. Main application calls `SetForegroundWindow` via P/Invoke to set the foreground window to its main shell window.

...or something along those lines.  It might have been the launcher who called `SetForegroundWindow` after waited for the app's main window to become active.  This was some time ago, and I no longer have access to the source.

Comment: Thanks Mike, it was actually easier in my case as I could just activate the window in the thread I was creating it, so no need to do it cross thread here. You answer helped me to find the answer, thanks.